# Stopwatch troubles

Tags: android, multithreading, android-custom-view, countdowntimer, stopwatch

I have Activity class and custom View element. I need to create stopwatch in my activity. Usage of regular stopwatch or threads to create it, is problematic. When stopwatch updates its time(when thread works) I can't affect on my view element, it can't track touches. Any use of threads in my activity will prevent to track touches on my custom view element. Advise me guys what I need to do.

P.S. Only CountDownTimer which located in custom View class works normally, but its a timer(I need stopwatch).

Comment: You cannot update the UI elements from an external thread. I can suggest that you use a producer-consumer based model, where one of your thread generates the texts that your view needs to display eventually and queue it in a concurrent queue. This thread will be the producer. The UI thread can then act as the consumer, and can actively poll for these texts from the concurrent queue. If they are available, it can update the text of your View. This approach will work. It is just one way of handling this thing. You can also look into asynchronous method calling for handling it in a different way.

Comment: All what you said I tried and it didn't work.
Someone I need another solutions.

Comment: Can I have a look at the code to see what all you tried?